# tsqlt error handling trumping stored procedure (unit) error handler

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

When trying to validate a user supplied GUID within a stored procedure a simple approach was used; take the user input as a CHAR(36) then explicitly CAST it as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER within a TRY CATCH. The CATCH then bubbles the error with a custom error description using a RAISERROR.

Running the stored procedure manually everything performs as expected and the error is raised.

Create a tSQLt test to call the unit (the procedure with GUID validation) and handle the error that is output and compare with the expected error continually fails with a transaction error; tSQLt has detected an error and handled within the tSQLt framework.

This suggests to me that the severity of a failure to CAST to a different datatype is being handled by tSQLt and it is preventing the TRY/CATCH within the stored procedure to handle it. Much like nested procedures sometimes ignore the TRY/CATCH within the child procedure and bubble up to the parent procedure; example being if the child proc. references a table that doesn't exist.

Has anyone had a similar issue? Just simply to validate my current line of thinking.

I've removed the test and it's being tested elsewhere, but this has caused me a 'hole' it my DB unit tests.

Finally, I think I should mention that I know I can perform a different validation on a supplied CHAR parameter, other than a CAST, and raise an error that way, but this is a tSQLt query and not a tSQL query.

EDIT

Example of the code:

@sGUID is a CHAR(36) and is a parameter passed to the procedure.

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT CAST(@sGUID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('Invalid GUID format',16,1)
END CATCH
```

The SELECT line never triggers the CATCH tSQLt appears to intervene before hand and throws the ROLLBACK transaction error.

Comment: Are you using any transactions in your stored procedures? Can you post some sample code.

Comment: No transactions in the procedure

Comment: Have you verified that @sGUID has a valid GUID format set for the value? In otherwords, a 36-digit string consisting of hex values only.

Comment: I have tried this out and it seems to work - it hits the catch block when I provide a non-GUID input.  Any chance that you're using an old version and this is fixed?  A repro case may be useful if you're on the latest version (which I am)

Comment: Luminary, can you please provide an example of your test procedure and what version of tSQLt you are using? There were some subtle changes recently in how tSQLt responds to errors that invalidate a transaction, and your cast might fit one of those errors. There was also a tSQLt.ExpectException procedure added which may help you in your test.

Answer (score 0):

When you call RAISEERROR(), you're terminating the transaction that tSQLt is running --> hence the transaction error you're seeing.

To improve this for the purpose of unit testing, one option you might consider would be to replace the RAISEERROR() statement with a call to a custom stored procedure that *only* contains RAISERROR().  That way, you can unit-test that stored procedure seperately.

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT CAST(@sGUID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC dbo.customprocedure
    --RAISERROR('Invalid GUID format',16,1)
END CATCH
```